# Solr doesnot accepts unparsed query

Tags: solr, solrj

I have added some documents in my solr index using requestHandler and now I am trying to query them from the web UI, I am getting the correct result when my query parameter is in the fomat

```
[id]:[search-item]
```

but i want to search it without parsing in this format, so for example i have to search for cat, i just type `"cat"` and it gives me the result, and not `"animal:cat"`, 
I am new to solr so I am not very sure, where am I going wrong

Comment: Use dismax. It's clearly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DisMax query parsers/handlers

Extract from [DisMax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) documentation

> The DisMax query parser is designed to process simple phrases (without
>   complex syntax) entered by users and to search for individual terms
>   across several fields using different weighting (boosts) based on the
>   significance of each field. Additional options enable users to
>   influence the score based on rules specific to each use case
>   (independent of user input).
>
> In general, the DisMax query parser's interface is more like that of
>   Google than the interface of the 'standard' Solr request handler. This
>   similarity makes DisMax the appropriate query parser for many consumer
>   applications. It accepts a simple syntax, and it rarely produces error
>   messages.

Also see [DisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMax) and full documentation of the [DisMax query parser here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, just some doubts, my solr version is 4.4.0 and dismax didnot work but replacing it with edismax worked, is it a support issue ?